# NSMutablearray insert a new element before or after other elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to dynamically insert a new element before or after a specific element?  Or must I copy the mutable array to another temporary mutable array and then "sort" the array?

Comment: Andrea, please revisit some of your answered questions and accept any answers you deem satisfactory.

Comment: Btw, documentation for things like NSMutableArray is just a click away in XCode. In the time it takes to post a question here, you coud have answered the question for yourself.

Comment: +1 for request to accept answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can insert an object at arbitrary index using `insertObject:atIndex:` method.

If you know just an object you can easily find its index in array (e.g. using indexOfObject: method)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[mutArray insertObject:anObject];

[mutArray insertObject:anObject1];

[mutArray insertObject:anObject2];

[mutArray insertObject:yourObject atIndex:1];
```

You can also insert at the end using `addObject:`.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the full documentation on `NSMutableArray`. It is definitively worth a read.

Comment: You cannot insert object at index larger than array's size - so before inserting object at index 3 you must add at least 3 elements to array

Comment: Zebs was just giving an example ,he dint mean just alloc and insert, that was implicit , so +1 to Zebs for correct answer

Comment: @Vladimir: You are absolutely right, I have updated the question to reflect your point.